# String utils split - linux

Tags: java, string, split, string-utils

Below Java code works in Windows machine

```
filepath = "euro\football\france\winners.txt";
String[] values = StringUtils.split(filePath, "\\");

if (values != null && values.length >= 4) {

} else {
    //error
}
```

But facing issue in linux while executing the code. if loop is not executing, else loop is executing.

Do we need to give split as "\" or "/" for linux

```
String[] values = StringUtils.split(filePath, "\\");
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Directories in linux paths are separated by forward-slashes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that I would use simple regex `[/\\]` which will split either with `/` or `\`, like this :

```
String[] filePaths = {
        "euro/football/france/winners.txt",   //linux path
        "euro\\football\\france\\winners.txt" //windows path
};
for (String filePath : filePaths) {
    String[] values = filePath.split("[/\\\\]");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Outputs

```
[euro, football, france, winners.txt]
[euro, football, france, winners.txt]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. filepath is dynamic - getting from headers with this "\". filePath.split("[/\\\\]"); hope it works for both

Comment: @Jessie When you test it, let me know please

Answer (score 2):

If the file is on the machine the JVM is running then you can use `File.separatorChar` to get the system-dependend separator of the local machine.

```
    String[] values = StringUtils.split(filePath, File.separator);
```

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar) says (`File.separatorChar`):

> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is
>   initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system
>   property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is
>   '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.